# Can Windows 10 work with headphone remotes?

Tags: macos, audio, boot-camp, remote, headphones

I'm running Windows 10 on my MacBook Pro but the headphone remote on my Beats Solo 2 doesn't do anything. In OS X, the remote works like how it would with an iPhone (press once to pause song, twice to skip song etc.) and the volume controls are really handy.

Seeing as the jack in my MacBook is *capable* of working with the headphone's remote, is there any way to enable this functionality in Windows? I've installed all of the Bootcamp drivers for Windows 10.

Any help would be great!